# couldn't connect to orientdb databases with java API

Tags: java, maven, orientdb

i have next problem and still can't resolve it. please can anybody help me?
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/orientechnologies/orient/core/storage/impl/local/OStorageRecoverListener

full error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/orientechnologies/orient/core/storage/impl/local/OStorageRecoverListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2251)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:810)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1253)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
at edu.ucla.sspace.doc.reader.SearchInterface.init(SearchInterface.java:50)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:698)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageRecoverListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
... 37 more
```

Now i have next code for connecting to databse:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/fulltext","root","root").setupPool(1,10);
```

my pom.xml dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
    <artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.orientechnologies/orientdb-enterprise -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-enterprise</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why are you using different versions in core, client and graphdb. Can you try with the latest 2.2.13?

Comment: You should need only`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

ok, the problem was that i'm connecting as root role. resolved by antering not root root, but with admin role. And it doesn;t depend to dependency)

Comment: ok, i try to delete one of them(exept orient graph), and my project was crushed. I have another codes and libraries which is used every dependency :) i need all of them. But one problem is that with orient-client and orient-core. For write and close database i neeed another version. For read from database for my interface i need another one. But it's no so big problem, cause i build and create database only once) but thanks for you) @RobertoFranchini

Comment: I don't really understand how it can works with such a mess of versions. All OrientDB versions must be the same AND if you're running a standalone server your application should use the same api version of your server. If changing dependency version your project doesn't complie, please fix complitation. But for sure, you can't go to production with these kind of deps  and hope that all will work. That said, do whatever you want. My 2€cents.